# Angular 5 -> Filter "like %" (we SQL)

Tags: sql, angular, typescript, filter

I have an Filter to an Array.

```
 filter(typ: string) {
console.log("Filter");
this.nagelplattenFiltered == null;
this.nagelplattenFiltered = this.nagelplatten.filter((nagel: Nagelplatten) => nagel.Bezeichnung1 === typ);
this.nagelplatten = this.nagelplattenFiltered;
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.nagelplattenFiltered));
console.log("new: " + JSON.stringify(this.nagelplattenFiltered));
```

}

So we can I make a Like 'var%' we in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. This operator doesn't exist in JavaScript. But you can use the indexOf()-method which has, used in the right way, a similar effect.

```
filter(typ: string) {
  console.log("Filter");
  this.nagelplattenFiltered == null;

  this.nagelplattenFiltered = this.nagelplatten.filter((nagel: Nagelplatten) => 
  nagel.Bezeichnung1.indexOf(typ) > -1);

  this.nagelplatten = this.nagelplattenFiltered;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.nagelplattenFiltered));
  console.log("new: " + JSON.stringify(this.nagelplattenFiltered));
}
```

Your filter now delivers all Nagel-objects that contain the type-string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i its all a type string. In the Array i have a Description ("20W, W101, 15N) so i would like to filter for example == W101) or (20W)

Comment: @StoRm Tec: I see, but indexOf() does this for you. It works the follwing: 1. find the string e.g. "SELECT * FROM Nagel WHERE Bezeichnung1 LIKE %W101%". 2. String found? Then return its starting index. -- So you then get an index greater than -1. And you can be sure that your Bezeichnung in Nagel contains the string you are searching for. If the string is not found you'll get -1 and filter() will ignore this entry. -- Did you already try it?

Comment: Glad to here that. Don't mention it. ;)